# Google publisher tag indicate multiple sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I want to show an ad of this dimensions 970x66 on my website, but in case we don't have an ad of that size I want to show one of 728x90 in it's place.

This is my current code:

```
window.googletag = window.googletag || {}
window.googletag.cmd = window.googletag.cmd || []
window.googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  googletag.
    defineSlot('/25283/SceneIndex_970x66', [970, 66], 'dfp_ad_8').
    addService(googletag.pubads());

  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
  googletag.enableServices();
});

googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('dfp_ad_8'); });
```

I thought maybe I could do this by indicating multiple sizes on the `defineSlot` method but this doesn't work as I expected.

With this code:

```
window.googletag = window.googletag || {}
window.googletag.cmd = window.googletag.cmd || []
window.googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  googletag.
    defineSlot('/25283/SceneIndex_728x90', [[970, 66], [728, 90]], 'dfp_ad_8').
    addService(googletag.pubads());

  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
  googletag.enableServices();
});

googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('dfp_ad_8'); });
```

This shows an empty `iframe` (currently I don't have any 970x60 ads) instead of showing 728x90 ads (which I do have).

The `google_console` shows this:

[image]

Is there a way of getting the desired behaviour? Showing 970x66 ads if possible and otherwise showing 728x90 ads.

Comment: Do you have delivering line items with both creative sizes targeted to this adunit?

Comment: @ffeast I will have, but for now I only have 728x90 ads.